# Split sqlite table at NULL

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite, split, null

I have an database that looks like the following:

```
 DT                      OB          OA         OL           OP  
"2015-01-21 00:12:00"   "1.15444"   "1.15467"   "1.15449"   "1.99999999999978"
"2015-01-21 00:32:00"   "1.15516"   "1.15468"   "1.15449"   "4.80000000000036"
"NULL"  "NULL"  "NULL"  "NULL"  "NULL"
"2015-01-21 01:06:00"   "1.15573"   "1.15534"   "1.15521"   "4.10000000000021"
"2015-01-21 08:04:00"   "1.15471"   "1.15582"   "1.15521"   "10.9000000000004"
"2015-01-21 08:10:00"   "1.15602"   "1.15514"   "1.15521"   "8.99999999999901"
"NULL"  "NULL"  "NULL"  "NULL"  "NULL"
"2015-01-21 02:32:00"   "1.15646"   "1.15615"   "1.15619"   "3.40000000000007"
"2015-01-21 05:18:00"   "1.15611"   "1.15644"   "1.15619"   "2.89999999999901"
"2015-01-21 05:30:00"   "1.15692"   "1.15631"   "1.15619"   "6.39999999999974"
"2015-01-21 07:32:00"   "1.15609"   "1.15685"   "1.15619"   "7.19999999999832"
"2015-01-21 07:42:00"   "1.15712"   "1.15643"   "1.15619"   "6.59999999999883"
"2015-01-21 07:56:00"   "1.15599"   "1.1567"    "1.15619"   "7.39999999999963"
"2015-01-21 08:40:00"   "1.15742"   "1.15628"   "1.15619"   "11.2000000000001"
"NULL"  "NULL"  "NULL"  "NULL"  "NULL"
"2015-01-21 03:40:00"   "1.15731"   "1.15664"   "1.15663"   "7.1000000000021"
"2015-01-21 04:34:00"   "1.15653"   "1.15684"   "1.15663"   "3.20000000000098"
```

I have been trying for some time to split the table at the null values, then do calculations on the "chunks" of the db. I have been trying to hack something out, but sometimes I have 2 or 3 NULL values in sequential rows, then sometimes I get a NULL at the end, or one or two NULL at the start which means doing it all using lists and indexes is quite frustrating.

I.e, this route:

```
dt = '2015-01-21'
ar2 = list([k[0] for k in cursor.execute("SELECT* FROM "+qi(dt)).fetchall()])

iters   = ([i+1 for i,k in enumerate(ar2) if k == None])
iters.append(0)
sit = sorted(iters,reverse = False)

kp = []
for k in range(0, len(sit)):
    if k < len(sit)-1:
        if k>1:
            start = str(sit[k-1]+1)
            fin   = str(sit[k]-1)

            oo = cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM "+qi(dt)+" WHERE rowid >= "+qi(start)+" AND rowid <= "+qi(fin)).fetchall()
```

I wouldn't recommend you try and make sense of what I am doing in that code, but can someone instead give a bit of advice on a better approach perhaps? Can Pandas do something like this with ease? My ears are open.

Thanks.

*Note that there re several hundred db's like this one, if it was just this one I would hack my way through it.

*EDIT

```
CREATE TABLE "2015-01-02" 
pair TEXT, 
side TEXT, 
t_time TEXT, 
open_price REAL, 
stop_loss REAL, 
p_line REAL, 
pip_risk REAL, 
max_min REAL, 
hour INTEGER, EOP REAL;
```

Comment: Is the problem that the query is sometimes returning the rows in the wrong order, and if so, what's the table schema?

Comment: schema posted in edit. No the problem is that I have been trying to do this for the best part of 3 hours, and sometimes I am still getting null values returned, messing up my calculations, I fear my approach is just fundamentally wrong.

Comment: To clarify, when you say "sometimes I have 2 or 3 NULL values in sequential rows", is that what's actually in the table, or are the rows just being returned in the wrong order?

Comment: @Aya Yes, some tables have been filled in that fashion, sometimes there just happen to be random amounts of nulls. I could of course rework the entire program, but that is an unattractive prospect.

Comment: Aside: your `select` appears not to have an `order by` clause. You have no guarantee that the rows will be returned in the order you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach is to use `itertools.groupby` to group your blocks of non NULL rows together. For testing purpose, I created my own table, in which the empty rows are the ones with all NULL values:

```
sqlite> SELECT * FROM data;
501,haiv
502,johnk
,
601,karenc
602,richardc
,
701,petery
702,paul
703,maryt
```

My code:

```
import sqlite3
from itertools import groupby

def is_empty_row(row):
    """ Return True if the row contains all None, False otherwise """
    return not any(row)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    db = sqlite3.connect('data.sqlite3')
    cursor = db.cursor()
    query = 'SELECT * FROM data'
    result = cursor.execute(query)
    for is_empty, rows_group in groupby(result, is_empty_row):
        if is_empty:
            # Skip the empty rows
            continue

        # At this point, the non empty rows are grouped together
        for row in rows_group:
            print(row)
        print('---')
```

Output:

```
(501, u'haiv')
(502, u'johnk')
---
(601, u'karenc')
(602, u'richardc')
---
(701, u'petery')
(702, u'paul')
(703, u'maryt')
---
```

In this approach, I created a helper function, `is_empty_row`, which returns True if the row is empty. The `groupby` function will group the rows sequence base on that classification. The rest of the code should not be hard to follow.

Comment: You are missing an `ORDER BY` clause. According to [the docs](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#orderby), "*If a SELECT statement that returns more than one row does not have an ORDER BY clause, the order in which the rows are returned is undefined.*".

Comment: Yes, I'll leave that to the original poster since I don't know how the PO's data ordered. The focus of my answer is in how grouping of the rows works.

Comment: @Robᵩ , thanks Rob, duly noted, but in all my time using SQL I have never had  a problem with the order of select statements: I just assumed returning the results as they were requested was the default method. If not I guess I have been incredibly lucky. Hence the language in the docs _" rows are returned is undefined" _  comes as a bit of a surprise.

Comment: My guess would be that the rows should always be returned in the same order they were originally added in, and assuming the table hasn't changed since then, then `ORDER BY rowid` should be what you need.